# Incrementing and \hrulefill problems in headers

Tags: columns, header

I am having two problems but I think they might be related. MWE below. I am compiling using LuaLaTeX.

There are two issues here. First of all, I have a counter macro which increments by 1. When I place that counter macro in the header it increments by some weird number. (My actual document is incrementing by 3, but his MWE below is incrementing by 4. I have no idea why.)

Secondly, I am using the `vwcol` package and have an `\hrulefill` command which seems to run off the edge of page. See image below.

So fundamentally I imagine that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how headers are working. Any clarifications would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
    \geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
    \geometry{margin=1.0in}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Verdana}

\newcommand{\makeheader}[3]{
    \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.55,0.45}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt] 
    \textbf{School} - \textbf{Stats 101}\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{#1}\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{#2}\\[0.01in]
    \\
    \textbf{Name \hrulefill}\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{Date \underline{#3} Block \hrulefill}\\[0.01in]
    \end{vwcol}
    \smallskip\hrule\bigskip 
}


\newcounter{wsnum}
\newcommand{\wscounter}{\stepcounter{wsnum}\#\thewsnum\,}
\newcounter{wsappliednum}
\newcommand{\wsappcounter}{\stepcounter{wsappliednum}\#\thewsappliednum\,}


\begin{document}
\makeheader{First Page}{Unit 1, Ch 1, WS \wscounter}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\wsappcounter \lipsum[1]

\newpage
\makeheader{Second Page}{Unit 1, Ch 2, WS \wscounter}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\wsappcounter\lipsum[2]


\newpage
\makeheader{Third Page}{Unit 1, Ch 3, WS \wscounter}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\wsappcounter\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal Working Example Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the source of both problems is `vwcol`. On the first page of the documentation, the author states: “Due to difficulties with the processing of such a thing, little else besides *text* is allowed within (feel free to experiment, but you’re on your own).” In order to get text into unequal columns, the text has to be manipulated several times -- each time the counter in incremented, giving rise to unexpected results. The faulty formatting (misplaced rules)  arises out of the same complex processing.

The answer to both problems is to use two `\parbox` constructions:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
    \geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
    \geometry{margin=1.0in}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    %\setmainfont{Verdana}

\newcommand{\makeheader}[3]{%
    \noindent
    \parbox{0.55\textwidth}{%
    \textbf{School} - \textbf{Stats 101}\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{#1}\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{#2}\\[0.01in]
    }%
    \parbox{0.45\textwidth}
    {\textbf{Name \hrulefill}\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{Date \underline{#3} Block \hrulefill}\\[0.01in]
    \smallskip}
    \hrule
    \bigskip
}


\newcounter{wsnum}
\newcommand{\wscounter}{\stepcounter{wsnum}\#\thewsnum\,}
\newcounter{wsappliednum}
\newcommand{\wsappcounter}{\stepcounter{wsappliednum}\#\thewsappliednum\,}


\begin{document}
\makeheader{First Page}{Unit 1, Ch 1, WS \wscounter}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\wsappcounter \lipsum[1]

\newpage
\makeheader{Second Page}{Unit 1, Ch 2, WS \wscounter}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\wsappcounter\lipsum[2]


\newpage
\makeheader{Third Page}{Unit 1, Ch 3, WS \wscounter}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\wsappcounter\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an automatic header would be more practical?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
    \geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
    \geometry{margin=1.0in}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Verdana}

\newcommand{\makeheader}[3]{%
    \stepcounter{wsnum}
    \def\mypage{#1}
    \def\myunit{#2 \#\thewsnum}
    \def\mydate{#3}
}


\newcounter{wsnum}
\newcommand{\wscounter}{\stepcounter{wsnum}\#\thewsnum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
        \textbf{School} - \textbf{Stats 101}\\[0.01in]
        \textbf{\mypage}\\[0.01in]
        \textbf{\myunit}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}% 
        \textbf{Name }\hrulefill\\[0.01in]
    \textbf{Date }\underline{\mydate} \textbf{Block }\hrulefill\\[0.01in]
    \mbox{}\\
  \end{minipage}%
}

\setlength{\headheight}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}

\makeheader{First Page}{Unit 1, Ch 1, WS}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\makeheader{Second Page}{Unit 1, Ch 2, WS}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\noindent\lipsum[2]

\newpage
\makeheader{Third Page}{Unit 1, Ch 3, WS}{23-26 Aug 2019}
\noindent\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]